# Addig more limitations to an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My query is like this:

```
@org = Org.includes(abc: [{def: :ghi}, :jkl_counts]).find(params[:id])
```

and it works, I am using it in a `respond_to :json ... respond_with(@org)`, passing it for parsing to JBuilder BUT the problem is that the returned Json will have all the tables.

I was hoping something like this would do it, but I was wrong, this doesn't even compile.

```
@org = Org.includes(abc: [{def: :ghi,  :order => "amount desc"}, :jkl]).find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try adding a has_many relationship in Measure like this:

```
has_many :ghis
has_many :highest_jkl_count_ghis, :limit => 20, :order => 'amount desc', :class_name => 'Ghi'
```

Then, for your @org instance do

```
@org = Org.includes(abcs: [{defs: :highest_jkl_count_ghis}, :jkl]).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Question: I was thinking when we use associations there should be corresponding model for them too, so in your example "highest_amount_targets" is just a made up name and doesn't need any real model ?

Comment: yeah didn't work, it is saying "uninitialized constant highest_amount_targets

Comment: awesome. Thanks for following up.